# Теория информации: энтропия

Tags: алгоритм

Дана задача: Подсчитать энтропию следующего сообщения:  10010011
Я решил ее следующим образом, по формуле из методического указания, но преподаватель говорит, что неверно. 
В чем я не прав?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а преподаватель дал какие-то еще комментарии?)

Comment: нет, просто в рецензии написал 
© "Энтропия вычислена неверно"

Comment: А что такое в данной формуле `X_i`? И чему оно равно для `i>8`?

Comment: Сумма всех вероятностей должна быть 1. А у вас что?

Comment: вывод формулы которую я привел, в МУ описывается так: Если перейти от символов источника к блокам символов длины L, то можно определить энтропию Lго порядка. Пусть X = {x1, x2, ... ,xL} — последовательность из L символов дискретного источника с алфавитом A. Тогда определим энтропию на блок символов источника как следующую формулу

Comment: Ну и чему в этой сумме будут равны x9, x10, ..., x256? Я к тому, что стоит задуматься, все ли в порядке с самой формулой?

Comment: в онлайн решебнике https://planetcalc.ru/2476/ пишет, что получается 1бит при введении 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 и включении игнорирования пробелов. Каким образом получился такой результат?

Comment: В конечном итоге взял обычную формулу Шеннона, посчитал по ней, получил ответ 1 и преподаватель зачел. Это кому будет интересно.